# Statistical test for comparing number of clusters in data

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, statistics, optimization, unsupervised-learning

I am performing $K$-means clustering on a dataset consisting of $n$ observations and $d$ variables, and I'm trying to determine the optimal number of clusters. Is there a test that can determine the statistical significance of adding another cluster?

I have considered the $F$-test with the following $F$-statistic

$$ F = \frac{ \Big( \frac{WCSS_k-WCSS_{k+1}}{d(k+1)-dk} \Big)}{ \Big( \frac{WCSS_{k+1}}{n-d(k+1)} \Big)} = \frac{ \Big( \frac{WCSS_k-WCSS_{k+1}}{d} \Big)}{ \Big( \frac{WCSS_{k+1}}{n-dk-1} \Big)}$$

where $WCSS_i$ is the within-cluster sum of squares, or inertia, for the model containing $i$ clusters. I obtained the general formula for the $F$-statistic [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test#:%7E:text=An%20F%2Dtest%20is%20any,which%20the%20data%20were%20sampled.) under "Regression Problems." In this case, I am treating inertia as a measure of error in the model, and $di$ is the number of parameters in the model with $i$ clusters because each of $i$ clusters has a $d$-dimensional mean vector at the center of the cluster.

Of course, adding another cluster will often reduce the inertia and never increase it... just as adding another predictor to a linear regression model will often reduce the RSS. The question is whether the reduction observed by adding another cluster is the result of clustering noise or the result of modelling a real pattern in the data. I am assuming a statistically significant p-value would indicate the latter.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure where this $F$-statistic comes from but it looks like an adopted Chow-Test. I will not dive deeper into this, since there is a  general problem, here:

**In general** you only try to optimize the within-cluster sum of squares. Your $F$-Test checks, if another cluster brings a significant improvement. The problem here is, that more clusters mean lower within-cluster sum of squares (there might be exceptions, but the general trend holds). The extreme case would be one cluster per sample (with zero within-cluster sum of squares). The significance test will prevent this extremum.

Still: more data samples from the same source/distribution will lead to more clusters. Hence looking **only at the within-cluster distances** will give you **no meaningful clusters**. It's more a question of the number of samples.

For this reason, one has to consider both, the **distances between and within clusters**. Measures from the literature are for example [the Davies-Bouldin-Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davies%E2%80%93Bouldin_index), [the Dunn-Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunn_index) or [Silhouette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)). These indices are no significance test, but it is common to use them to find an optimal number of clusters from a range of potential numbers.